# running script through ssh fails when locally same script succeeds

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior.  I have found what appears to be a work around, but I am hoping that someone can explain to me WHY I'm seeing this crazy behavior.

Highlevel of what I'm doing: I'd like to have a shell script to stop my process.  I'd like it to be robust enough to kill one or more instances of the process I'm grepping for.  I don't want it to fail if there's NO process running (meaning I want a 0 return code...not an empty arg list passed to the kill command)

What I'm seeing is that a script is behaving differently when invoked by passing a command through ssh than if that same script was executed locally.  What is very strange is that by adding a seemingly arbitrary command to my ssh command, I'm able to get my script to execute properly and I DONT KNOW WHY!

The stop scipt (echo statments were there to help me debug - not part of real script)

> `echo "Stopping myProcess"
>   echo "-->`ps aux | grep myProcess | grep -v grep`"
>   pid=`ps -ef | grep myProcess | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'
>   `echo "Here: ${pid}"
>   if [[ ! -z $pid ]]; then
>   echo "Here2"
>   kill -9 $pid
>   else
>   echo "Here3"
>   echo "not stopping anything - no myProcess process running."
>   fi
>   echo "Here4"
>   exit 0`

Result of local execution of script when NO processes is running:

> `Stopping myProcess
>   -->
>   Here:
>   Here3
>   not stopping anything - no myProcess running.
>   Here4`

Result of execution of script from a different machine though the following command:

Command:

> ssh eak0703@myServer 'source ${HOME}/.bash_profile;cd /usr/local/myprocess/bin/;./stop-myProcess'

Result:

> `Stopping myProcess
>   --> eak0703  2099  0.0  0.0  10728  1500 ?        Ss   17:08   0:00 bash -c source ${HOME}/.bash_profile;cd /usr/local/myProcess/bin/;./stop-myProcess
>   eak0703  2100  0.0  0.0  10740   992 ?        S    17:08   0:00 bash -c source ${HOME}/.bash_profile;cd /usr/local/myProcess/bin/;./stop-myProcess
>   eak0703  2101  0.0  0.0  10740   668 ?        S    17:08   0:00 bash -c source ${HOME}/.bash_profile;cd /usr/local/myProcess/bin/;./stop-myProcess
>   Here: 2099
>   2100
>   2105
>   Here2`

Notice: for some strange and unexplained to me reason there appear to be 3 invocations of my command. I also know that this command doesn't terminate with an exit code of 0.  I am assuming this is because by the time the kill -9 is invoked, the process ids picked up by the grep are gone.

Now - here's the SAME ssh command with an extra "date | grep crap" thrown in:

Command:

> ssh eak0703@myServer 'source ${HOME}/.bash_profile;cd /usr/local/myprocess/bin/;date | grep crap;./stop-myProcess'

Result:

> `Stopping myProcess
>   -->
>   Here:
>   Here3
>   not stopping anything - no myProcess running.
>   Here4`

Putting "date | grep crap" fixes things.  It appears that the magic is in the "|" (pipe) operator.  So I am actually able to make this work with "anycommand | anyothercommand".

I can make it work - but how can I justify randomly leaving such a nugget in a bash script??? No one will ever know why this is there. Not even me! If anyone has encountered this please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing `ps` to find a process is fragile and error prone. Your example is a nice illustration why:

An unrelated process (the `bash` process started by `ssh`) contains the process name as part of the command line, and is accidentally picked up by your `ps` parser.

The unrelated process is removed by your `grep -v grep` when you make the command line include the word "grep".

Instead, just use `pgrep` or `pkill`. These tools list/kill processes based on the executable name and are therefore far more robust than parsing `ps`.

Comment: Yep! This is correct.  I still wonder why there seem to be 3 "instances" of my bash command running?

Comment: Also - for anyone who is trying to kill one of possibly a few processes with the same name (eg: java) but different arguments and would like to use pkill/pgrep they should probably use the `-f` flag so that the query is `Matched against full argument lists.  The default is to match against process names.`

Comment: @eak0703 1. the `bash` process invoked by ssh, 2. the fork that executes your `./stop-myProcess` script because it doesn't have a shebang, and 3. the subshell from your command substitution.